# Redirect already Rewriten URL with parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In order to edit my actual URL structure. I need to redirect my "old" links to keep the incoming links active.

Everything is working fine, however it doesn't work when the "old" links have parameters.

Here is the first part of my .htaccess (which is working) :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite the "old" url "/models" to "/models-pictures"
RewriteRule ^/?models/?$ /models-pictures [R=301,NE,L]

# New redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /models-pictures/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . models.php [L]
```

And now the second part which is not redirecting

```
# Rewrite the "old" url "/models/[name]-pictures" to "/[name]-pictures" 
RewriteRule ^/?models/([a-z\-A-Z]+)-pictures/?$ /%1-pictures [R=301,NE,L] <- Not working

# New redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z\-A-Z]+)-pictures/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . orderby.php?model=%1 [L,QSA]

# New redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z\-A-Z]+)-pictures/([a-z\-A-Z]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . p.php?model=%1&media=%2 [L,QSA]
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Use `$1` and not `%1` in `/$1-pictures`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct back reference in the substitution string in the not working rule. You have `%1` and it should be `$1`.

```
# Rewrite the "old" url "/models/[name]-pictures" to "/[name]-pictures" 
RewriteRule ^/?models/([a-z\-A-Z]+)-pictures/?$ /$1-pictures [R=301,NE,L]
```